# How to add type information to JavaScript sequelize.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I recently inherited a legacy project and am trying to add some type information. It's the first time I'm using sequelize and I guess I'm just doing it wrong.

This is what I have (kind of):

FooModel.js:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    config.moreConfig
);
module.exports = {
  Foo: sequelize.define(
      'Foo',
      {
        someText: STRING,
      }
  )
};
```

FooModel.d.ts:

```
declare class FooModel extends Model<InferAttributes<FooModel>, InferCreationAttributes<FooModel>> {

  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare someText: string;
}

export const Foo: ModelStatic<FooModel>;
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
Foo.findOne({where:{someText: 'foo'}});
```

But my IDE complains about the last line: "Argument types do not match parameters". I tried to follow the [typescript-guide](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/), but it looks like I missed something.

The sequelize version in use is `6.24.0`.

I am not using `sequelize-typescript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `sequelize-typescript`. It seems to be the best way to work with sequelize in a more or less typesafe way.